All my old embedded youtube video show error suddenly
I have app working well for more than 6 months
and youtube channel share the videos via it
suddenly from 2 hours before
all youtube videos don't load on mobile app and show (Error while playing videos)
but working well on the website
any help?

Faced the same issue and resolved it by upgrading the pod player to the latest version. pod_player: ^0.2.2. In the process of upgrading the plugin, I needed to upgrade flutter as well.
